# Javascript Global Scope not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand global scoping in js so that i can call a var from a different server into a webpage and access with js, but this simple test is not even working.

remote php script 'remotescript.php' includes:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
window.myValue=5;
</script>
```

Local page includes:

```
<div class='widget-content'>
<script language='javascript' src='remotescript.php' type='text/javascript'>
</script>
hi!
</div>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
alert(window.myValue);
</script>
```

I get 'undefined' in the alert.

Any clue what I'm doing wrong, or if this should even work?
tyvmia

Comment: Take care when making such big changes to the post such that it removes the problem! This is *not* what was initially posted and will work as expected.

Comment: OK thank you - so what i really want now is to set the var in that external script, and see it in the local page.  is it possible?

Comment: All the scripts on the same page share the same global (`window`) object and so that should work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Your external script remotescript.php doesn't work because it has `<script>` tags inside it - you need to remove those and just include the JavaScript code. So in your simple example your remotescript.php should include just the following line:

```
window.myValue=5;
```

Or you could use `var`:

```
var myValue = 5;
```

(Note also that you don't need `language='javascript'` on any of your script elements.)

**Original answer** from original version of the question:

It won't work if you include JS statements inside a script element that is a link to an external script (this doesn't just apply to creating variables, it applies to any statements). Close the external script and then start a new script element:

```
<div class='widget-content'>
<script language='javascript' src='http://example.com/files/blockip.php' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
var myValue=5;
</script>
hi!
</div>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
alert(myValue);
</script>
```

If you declare globals in the external file that will also work. Multiple scripts can access each other's variables if they are globals.

Comment: thanks - is it possible to set the var in the external script?  I was trying that first, was why the external script was there.

Comment: Yes - when that didn't work, i started fiddling around with setting it locally and couldn't get even that working.

Comment: I see you've now changed your question to remove the external script altogether. I suggest if you're having problems with the external one you should include details of that in the question. (The code in the current version of the question should work fine.) In a general sense a global variable or function declared in an external script will be accessible to any other script (internal or external) on the page, noting that the scripts will be executed in the order they are included so you'd need to include the one with the declaration first.

Comment: ok now that i'm past this, i will revise the question to ask what i really want.  thank you.

Comment: OK, answer updated to explain why your external script doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks!  That was it, and my troubleshooting attempt only compounded my confusion!